# ListPreference tag causes my app to crash

Tags: java, android, crash, listpreference

I tried a sample code [Android Settings Example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/settings/android-settings-example/) from Java Code Geek.

I have a problem when I click on the settings floating action bar: App crashes due to:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
>   Process: com.sano.tamer.androidsettings, PID: 32035
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
> ComponentInfo{com.sano.tamer.androidsettings/com.sano.tamer.androidsettings.SettingsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor

And when i commented ListPreference tag, it works, and opened the preference activity, i copied and pasted the preference file, so what is the problem?
I am using Android studio 2.1.2

Thank you

my device is Asus Fonepad 7 FE375CG, running Kitkat

And here is the complete error log:

```
07-23 07:06:28.629 5034-5034/com.sano.tamer.androidsettings E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.sano.tamer.androidsettings, PID: 5034
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sano.tamer.androidsettings/com.sano.tamer.androidsettings.SettingsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2318)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5252)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
  at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:397)
  at android.preference.GenericInflater.onCreateItem(GenericInflater.java:417)
  at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:428)
  at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:481)
  at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:493)
  at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:326)
  at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:263)
  at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:272)
  at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceActivity.java:1472)
  at com.sano.tamer.androidsettings.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:11)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5403)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5252) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610) 
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
  at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:383)
  at android.preference.GenericInflater.onCreateItem(GenericInflater.java:417) 
  at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:428) 
  at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:481) 
  at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:493) 
  at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:326) 
  at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:263) 
  at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:272) 
  at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceActivity.java:1472) 
  at com.sano.tamer.androidsettings.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:11) 
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5403) 
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5252) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610) 
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceTextArray(AssetManager.java:215)
  at android.content.res.Resources.getTextArray(Resources.java:454)
  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getTextArray(TypedArray.java:629)
  at android.preference.ListPreference.<init>(ListPreference.java:51)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
  at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:383) 
  at android.preference.GenericInflater.onCreateItem(GenericInflater.java:417) 
  at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:428) 
  at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:481) 
  at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:493) 
  at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:326) 
  at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:263) 
  at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:272) 
  at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceActivity.java:1472) 
  at com.sano.tamer.androidsettings.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:11) 
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5403) 
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5252) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610) 
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Share your xml code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is in facting happening here:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceTextArray(AssetManager.java:215)
  at android.content.res.Resources.getTextArray(Resources.java:454)
  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getTextArray(TypedArray.java:629)
  at android.preference.ListPreference.<init>(ListPreference.java:51)
```

So, it seems a null pointer while reading TextArray.

Looking layout XML, I can see that your `ListPreference` uses two arrays:

```
<ListPreference
    ...
    android:entries="@array/entries_text"
    android:entryValues="@array/entries_values" 
    ... />
```

So, double check your file `res/values/string.xml` and confirm that you have both arrays created: `entries_text` and `entries_values`

```
<string-array name="entries_text">
    <item>entries 1</item>
    <item>entries 2</item>
    <item>entries 3</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="entries_values">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: Your answer is very helpful and it solved my problem.

The problem was that i downloaded the code sample and found the array entries and its values in a separate file, not in the strings.xml file, so i copied it and pasted it into my project xml folder, when i copied the entries and the values into the strings.xml file, it worked

Comment: Sorry, i am new to the StackOverFlow, how i accept the answer? by clicking the up arrow?, i did it

Comment: Sorry, i am new to the StackOverFlow, how i accept the answer? by clicking the up arrow?, i did it